# Updating column and insert a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to accomplish to update the column `ListPrice` adding `25` to its current value where the name is `All-Purpose Bike Stands` and update `SellStartDate` to tomorrow's date in the table `Production.Product`.

Using that updated price I want to insert a row into the table `Production.ProductListHistory` with the new `ListPrice` and also update the row in the `Production.ProductHistory` column named `EndDate` with tomorrow's date as well.

The tables definitions areas follows:

`Production.Product`:

```
ProductID int PK
Name varchar(50)
ProductNumber nvarchar(25)  
ListPrice  money
SellStartDate datetime
SellEndDate
```

`Production.ProductListHistory`:

```
ProductID int PK FK
StartDate datetime PK
EndDate datetime
ListPrice money
```

Here is what I have so far that continues to give me errors:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_AND_INSERT
    (@newprice money)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
    SET @newprice = 25 + AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product.ListPrice
    WHERE AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product.Name LIKE 'All-Purpose%'

    @newprice = AdventureProduct.Production.Listprice
END
```

Comment: The problem reads as such. I need to up the list price $25 to take advantage of the sell. The price is set to increase starting tomorrows. Update the list price of this item in the Products, and insert a record into the list price history establishing the new bench mark. Also update the end date for the previous selling price by updating that record in history.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, Your `UPDATE` should be something like this

You can also create a table variable to store your deleted list price and then insert it into your history table

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
ProductID int NOT NULL,
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime,
ListPrice money);

UPDATE AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
Set ListPrice = 25 + AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product.ListPrice
OUTPUT inserted.ProductID,
       inserted.SellStartDate,
       inserted.SellEndDate,
       deleted.ListPrice
INTO @MyTableVar 
where AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product.Name Like 'All-Purpose%'
AND Listprice = AdventureProduct.Production.Listprice
```

Comment: Also refer to this link to know the correct syntax for creating procedure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx